# How to retrieve firebase data in sequence

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, iot

[This is how the data stored in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSMLZ.png)

[image]

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mzvd.png)

[image]

This is the code

```
from firebase import firebase
url = "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/"
fb = firebase.FirebaseApplication(url,None)
Humidity = fb.get("/Humidity",None)
for key, value in Humidity.items():
    print("Humidity :{}".format(value["hum"]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
snapshot = ref.order_by_child('/Humidity').get()
```

for more look at this link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data